# How to add potential owner for dynamic creation BPMN via API?

Tags: jbpm, fluent-interface

I'm trying to follow this document (https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/release/7.3.0.Final/jbpm-docs/html_single/#_process_fluent_api) to use jBPM fluent api to create a process. But I'm wondering how to add potential owner for a task? I saw some document mentioned this function is provided by `UserTaskAdminService`, but I don't see any example for how to get an instance of this interface, especial in process creation phase.

Very appreciate if anyone has the experience for create a process from scratch by code, thanks!

Comment: Are you asking owner for HumanTasks? Did you try using actorid from "HumanTaskNodeFactory" for eg -: humanTaskNode(1).name("usertask").taskName("name").actorId("username")

Comment: I tried, it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you getting any error? or even if you login with given id the task is not shown?

Comment: No error, task just not showing if searching by potential owner

Comment: I'm able to do it by using Camunda BPM fluent API now, which is much more better then jBPM.